# Server returned HTTP response code: 500. Java app

Tags: java, http-status-code-500

I am making simple request from Spring Boot app to URL.

```
URL url = new URL("http://...:8001/api/meta");

HttpURLConnection urlConnect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
int code = urlConnect.getResponseCode(); 
...
```

**code = 500**. Then an error occurs:

> Server returned HTTP response code: 500.

Also **urlConnect.getErrorStream = null**

**If I put the url to browser then I successfully get json.**

What should be done to fix the issue?

Comment: 500 means an error on the server, not your client.

Comment: response code usually means, problem is on server side, so you should chech server side code to check what actually happened.

Comment: I don't think it is a server problem as I successfully get json when I put the url into browser.

Comment: Maybe track what actually goes on the line using NMAP or something alike. I guess there will be a difference between the requests from browser and URL.openConnection.

Comment: You may need to add "Accept: application/json" in your request.

Comment: Have you tried [URL.openStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream--) ?

Comment: Yes. I have already tried URL.openStream() - it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added:

```
urlConnect.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
```

then I can successfully get the response.